# Navigation bar not occupying entire screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Im trying to create a `UINavigationBar` using storyboard but the `UINavigationBar` is not occupying the entire screen.

Following is the screen shot of my storyboard.
[image]

In storyboard, it appears to occupy full screen width but in my device, the width is not full. How can I sort this out?

Comment: use autolayout ...and give  top , leading , trailing and fixed height constraints

Comment: are you used the navigation bar in single View conrtroller or multiple

Comment: you want custom navigationbar or default????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select your viewController and go to `XCode Menu`  - > `Editor`  -> `select Navigation Controller` ,

for example

[image]

you get the output of

[image]

it works fine for any layout patterns

Answer (score 1):

firstly you have to disable size classes and auto layout in the file inspecter for your view after then set your navigation bar property like as shown in screenshot. It will be applicable for all the devices.

[image]

Comment: but if i try to include a button within it, the alignment of button changes and the button appears at the centre instead of corner

Comment: @user22312412 -- if you modify your layout , other UIcontrols will also get modified.

Answer (score 0):

use `autoresizing` selecting your `NavigationBar`:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1- Select your element.

2- Click triangle button at bottom right.

3- Click Add Missing Constraints

[image: Adding missing constraints xcode 7]